# Recycler view showing only one item from the shared preference in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-studio-2.0

I am having a problem Recycler View doesn't display all the item for my wish list. I get the product ID from Shared Preference, so i have three IDs in shared preference, but it's showing only one item in Recycler View.

Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_wishlist__items);
     powers = new ArrayList < String > ();
     recyleitems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mywishitems);

     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     if (toolbar != null) {
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ds);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
         shared = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

         cartitemsdisplay();




     }

 }




 /********************************************************  start ***************************************************************/
 public void cartitemsdisplay() {
     String channel = (shared.getString(Constants.productid, "['']"));
     try {
         listitems = new JSONArray(channel);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }


     if (listitems.length() > 0) {
         String items = String.valueOf(listitems);
         for (int i = 0; i < listitems.length(); i++)

         {

             try {
                 list = listitems.getString(i);
                 Log.d(list, "listnew");

                 if ("".equals(list)) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "empty null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } else {

                     Wishproduct();



                 }

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }



         }



     } else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Items in the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }


 }

 public void Wishproduct() {

     String wishlisturl = "http://192.168.0.33/cartwebsite3/qcrest1.0/?type=productDisplay&result=json&product_id=" + list;
     //  showpDialog();
     JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, wishlisturl, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
             Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());




             if (jsonObject != null) {
                 //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");
                 data = new ArrayList < CartitemModel > ();
                 String status = jsonObject.optString("status");
                 if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { //check the status 200 or not
                     try {
                         productpath = jsonObject.getString("productPath");
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                     try {
                         JSONObject jsonobj1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                         JSONArray jsonarr1 = jsonobj1.getJSONArray("data");
                         if (jsonarr1.length() > 0) {
                             for (int j = 0; j < jsonarr1.length(); j++) {
                                 JSONObject wishitems = jsonarr1.getJSONObject(j);
                                 String prodcutname = wishitems.getString("product_name");
                                 String product_alias = wishitems.getString("product_alias");
                                 String mrpprice = wishitems.getString("mrp_price");
                                 String selling_price = wishitems.getString("selling_price");
                                 String seller = wishitems.getString("seller_id");

                                 /************************  calculation of  prices******************************/
                                 Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                                 String ts = tsLong.toString();
                                 int ts1 = Integer.parseInt(ts);
                                 String offerprice = wishitems.getString("offer_selling_price");
                                 String startdate1 = wishitems.getString("offer_selling_start_date");
                                 String endate1 = wishitems.getString("offer_selling_end_date");

                                 /************************************ end ***********************************************/

                                 JSONArray productimages = wishitems.getJSONArray("product_images");

                                 JSONObject images = productimages.getJSONObject(0);
                                 final String image = images.getString("original_res");
                                 String[] img2 = image.split("\\.");
                                 String imagone = productpath + seller + '/' + img2[0] + '(' + '2' + '0' + '0' + ')' + '.' + img2[1];

                                 data.add(new CartitemModel(prodcutname, product_alias, mrpprice, selling_price, offerprice, imagone))

                             }
                         }


                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }




                 } // condtion check the status 200
                 else // this is if status falied in runtime
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(wishlist_Items.this, "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }




             LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(wishlist_Items.this);
             llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
             recyleitems.setLayoutManager(llm);
             wishadapter = new WishlistAdapter(data, wishlist_Items.this);
             recyleitems.setAdapter(wishadapter);
             wishadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());
             Toast.makeText(wishlist_Items.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             // stopping swipe refresh
             //   swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
         }
     });

     // Adding request to request queue
     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);



 }
```

Adapter

```
public class WishlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < WishlistAdapter.ViewHolder > {

        private ArrayList < CartitemModel > WishListadp;
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        private Context context;

        public WishlistAdapter(ArrayList < CartitemModel > WishListadp, Context context) {

            this.WishListadp = WishListadp;
            this.context = context;
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.b2)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2).build();
            if (YelloPage.imageLoader.isInited()) {
                YelloPage.imageLoader.destroy();
            }
            YelloPage.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));


        }

        @Override
        public WishlistAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wishitemsrow, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(WishlistAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            viewHolder.iteamname.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getCartitemname());
            viewHolder.itemalisname.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getAliasname());
            viewHolder.wishmrp.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getWishmrp());
            viewHolder.wishselling.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getWishsellingprice());
            viewHolder.wishoffer.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getWishoffer());
            viewHolder.wishratingcount.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getRatingcount());
            // viewHolder.wishrating.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getCartitemname());

            viewHolder.iteamname.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getCartitemname());
            YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(WishListadp.get(i).getImage(), viewHolder.wishitemimage, options);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return WishListadp.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView iteamname, itemalisname, wishmrp, wishselling, wishoffer, wishratingcount;
            private ImageView wishitemimage;
            RatingBar wishrating;
            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                iteamname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
                itemalisname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aliasname);
                wishselling = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishselling);
                wishmrp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishmrp);
                wishoffer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wishoffer);
                wishratingcount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingtxt);
                wishrating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rtbProductRating);
                wishitemimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pimage);




            }
        }

    }
```

Logcat

```
05-20 01:55:19.375 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/3: listnew
05-20 01:55:19.377 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/2: listnew
05-20 01:55:19.377 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/10: listnew
05-20 01:55:19.458 6365-6408/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-20 01:55:19.458 6365-6408/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdec24400, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-20 01:55:19.499 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
05-20 01:55:19.546 6365-6408/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-20 01:55:19.546 6365-6408/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdef66540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-20 01:55:19.636 6365-6408/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer V/RenderScript: 0xdee76000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
05-20 01:55:19.662 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/wishlist_Items: {"status":"200","requestType":"productDisplay","basePath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/","bannerPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/","productPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/prd\/","response":{"data":[{"product_id":"3","seller_id":"1","product_active":"on","product_name":"Micromax Unite 3","product_alias":"(Blue, 8 GB)","product_sku":"21334","product_manufacturer_country":"India","product_manufacturer":"india","product_min_add":"1","product_max_add":"100","short_description":"Slim, compact and user-friendly, the Micromax Unite 3 is a good combination of powerful performance and nifty features for a great smartphone experience.","long_description":"Slim, compact and user-friendly, the Micromax Unite 3 is a good combination of powerful performance and nifty features for a great smartphone experience.","product_quantity":"0","quantity":"100","status":"In Stock","price_id":"4","mrp_price":"5900.0000","selling_price":"5099.0000","offer_percentage":"","product_weight":"130g","offer_selling_price":"2000.0000","offer_selling_percentage":"","offer_selling_start_date":"1461621600","offer_selling_end_date":"1469484000","shipping_cost":"0.0000","product_images":[{"image_id":"18","product_id":"3","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"micromax-unite-3-951452579749.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579749","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"19","product_id":"3","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"micromax-unite-3-241452579749.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579749","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"20","product_id":"3","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"micromax-unite-3-301452579749.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579749","added_user":"1","sort":"0"}],"basic_info":[{"basic_id":"550","product_id":"3","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Android v5 OS","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"551","product_id":"3","option_name":"Features","option_description":"8 MP Primary Camera","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"552","product_id":"3","option_name":"Features","option_description":"2MP Secondary Camera","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"553","product_id":"3","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Dual Sim (GSM   WCDMA)","have_connected":"0"}],"extra_info":[{"type":"textfield","main_header":"Micromax Unite 3(Blue, 8 GB)","field_option":[{"inside_single_title":"Specifications","basic_opt1":[{"option_name_extra":"In the Box","option_desc_extra":"Handset, USB Cable, Charger, User Guide, Warranty Card, Battery, Hands-free"},{"option_name_extra":"Sensors","option_desc_extra":"Light Sensor, Gravity Sensor, Proximity Sensor"},{"option_name_extra":"User Memory\t","option_desc_extra":"4.9 GB for Apps and Phone Storage"},{"option_name_extra":"Processor","option_desc_extra":"1.3 GHz   MTK 6582M, Quad Core"}]}]}],"category_list":[{"category_id":"46","category_name":"ELECTRONICS","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"electronics"},{"category_id":"48","category_name":"Mobiles","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"mobiles"},{"category_id":"54","category_name":"Micromax","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"micromax"}]}]},"request":{"postData":[],"getData":{"type":"productDisplay","result":"json","product_id":"3"}}}
05-20 01:55:19.678 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/wishlist_Items: {"status":"200","requestType":"productDisplay","basePath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/","bannerPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/","productPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/prd\/","response":{"data":[{"product_id":"2","seller_id":"1","product_active":"on","product_name":"Lenovo A6000","product_alias":"(Black, 8 GB)","product_sku":"258148562","product_manufacturer_country":"India","product_manufacturer":"india","product_min_add":"1","product_max_add":"1000","short_description":"The Lenovo A6000 is a smartphone designed for multimedia and music lovers on a budget.","long_description":"The Lenovo A6000 is a smartphone designed for multimedia and music lovers on a budget. It features a 5 wide-view HD display that offers good resolution. It also has a Snapdragon quad core processor that delivers responsive system performance.","product_quantity":"0","quantity":"150","status":"In Stock","price_id":"3","mrp_price":"7500.0000","selling_price":"7099.0000","offer_percentage":"","product_weight":"146g","offer_selling_price":"0.0000","offer_selling_percentage":"","offer_selling_start_date":"","offer_selling_end_date":"","shipping_cost":"0.0000","product_images":[{"image_id":"12","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-171452579105.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"13","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-791452579106.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"14","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-971452579106.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"15","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-341452579106.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"16","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-891452579106.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"17","product_id":"2","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"lenovo-a6000-441452579106.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452579106","added_user":"1","sort":"0"}],"basic_info":[{"basic_id":"9","product_id":"2","option_name":"Features","option_description":"5 inch HD IPS Display","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"10","product_id":"2","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Twin Dolby Speaker","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"11","product_id":"2","option_name":"Features","option_description":"1.2 GHz Quad Core","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"12","product_id":"2","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Dual SIM,4G LTE","have_connected":"0"}],"extra_info":[{"type":"textfield","main_header":"Lenovo A6000(Black, 8 GB)","field_option":[{"inside_single_title":"Specifications","basic_opt1":[{"option_name_extra":"Network Type","option_desc_extra":"4G, 3G"},{"option_name_extra":"Standby Time","option_desc_extra":"264 hrs (2G), 264 hrs (3G)"},{"option_name_extra":"OS","option_desc_extra":"Android v38081 (KitKat)"},{"option_name_extra":"Graphics","option_desc_extra":"Adreno 306; 400 MHz Speed"}]}]}],"category_list":[{"category_id":"46","category_name":"ELECTRONICS","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"electronics"},{"category_id":"48","category_name":"Mobiles","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"mobiles"},{"category_id":"51","category_name":"Lenovo","category_des
05-20 01:55:19.685 6365-6365/com.journaldev.navigationdrawer D/wishlist_Items: {"status":"200","requestType":"productDisplay","basePath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/","bannerPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/","productPath":"http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/prd\/","response":{"data":[{"product_id":"10","seller_id":"1","product_active":"on","product_name":"Micromax Canvas Nitro 2","product_alias":"(White  Gold, 16 GB)","product_sku":"143234354","product_manufacturer_country":"India","product_manufacturer":"micromax","product_min_add":"1","product_max_add":"100","short_description":"Watch a trending 9GAG video in HD while you check your text messages, or take breathtaking snaps of passing scenery from your car with this impressive smartphone.","long_description":"Watch a trending 9GAG video in HD while you check your text messages, or take breathtaking snaps of passing scenery from your car with this impressive smartphone.","product_quantity":"0","quantity":"1000","status":"In Stock","price_id":"11","mrp_price":"8500.0000","selling_price":"7800.0000","offer_percentage":"","product_weight":"150g","offer_selling_price":"0.0000","offer_selling_percentage":"","offer_selling_start_date":"1461621600","offer_selling_end_date":"1467064800","shipping_cost":"0.0000","product_images":[{"image_id":"21","product_id":"10","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"micromax-canvas-nitro-2-131452580405.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452580405","added_user":"1","sort":"0"},{"image_id":"22","product_id":"10","image_small":"","image_medium":"","image_large":"","original_res":"micromax-canvas-nitro-2-161452580405.jpeg","image_type":"jpeg","added_date":"1452580405","added_user":"1","sort":"0"}],"basic_info":[{"basic_id":"546","product_id":"10","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Android v4.4.2 OS","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"547","product_id":"10","option_name":"Features","option_description":"13 MP Primary Camera","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"548","product_id":"10","option_name":"Features","option_description":"5MP Secondary Camera","have_connected":"0"},{"basic_id":"549","product_id":"10","option_name":"Features","option_description":"Dual Sim (GSM   WCDMA)","have_connected":"0"}],"extra_info":[{"type":"textfield","main_header":"Micromax Canvas Nitro 2(White  Gold, 16 GB)","field_option":[{"inside_single_title":"Specifications ","basic_opt1":[{"option_name_extra":"Other Camera Features","option_desc_extra":"Auto Focus, Touch Focus, Face Detection, Smile Detection, Scene Modes, HDR, Face Beauty"},{"option_name_extra":"Additional Features","option_desc_extra":"Organizer, World Clock, To-do List, Reminders, Notes, Calendar, Calculator, Clock, Backup and Restore, Call Waiting, Multi-languages Supported, 5-pin Micro USB Port"},{"option_name_extra":"Resolution","option_desc_extra":"HD, 1280 x 720 Pixels"},{"option_name_extra":"Memory","option_desc_extra":"2 GB RAM, 16 GB ROM"}]}]}],"category_list":[{"category_id":"46","category_name":"ELECTRONICS","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"electronics"},{"category_id":"48","category_name":"Mobiles","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"mobiles"},{"category_id":"54","category_name":"Micromax","category_desc":"","category_image":"","category_thumbnail":"","category_image_desc":"","category_meta_title":"","category_meta_desc":"","category_meta_keyword":"","category_show_hide":"0","category_vanity":"micromax"}]}]},"request":{"postData":[],"getData":{"type":"productDisplay","result":"json","product_id":"10"}}}
```

Anyone solve my problem.
Glad to appreciate Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your `for` loop you are creating new instance of `data` on each loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < jsonarr1.length(); j++) {
    //your code
    data = new ArrayList<CartitemModel>();
    data.add(new CartitemModel(prodcutname, product_alias, mrpprice, selling_price, offerprice, imagone));
}
```

and you need do like this

```
data = new ArrayList<CartitemModel>();
for (int j = 0; j < jsonarr1.length(); j++) {
    //your code
    data.add(new CartitemModel(prodcutname, product_alias, mrpprice, selling_price, offerprice, imagone));
}
```

Comment: I put new instance above  for loop,  but showing only one item when I will click my wish routinely change the items only one displayed

Comment: still only one item displaying

Comment: I got i put that new instance in onCreate got output now

Comment: Thanks a lot  I did this mistake quite before also, but  I forget anyways thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen also if you are set your item layout of adapter height to match parent, so the next list will not visible, just scroll your page up, to make sure how many item are there.